# Jenkins cannot read files even with read permission

Tags: jenkins, centos7

I have Jenkins installed on CentOS 7. I have a pipeline that run a simple command

```
steps
     {
        sh label: '', script: 'ls -l /DATA00/tomcat/tomcat-orion/lib/annotations-api.jar'
     }
```

Here's the output:

`ls: cannot access /DATA00/tomcat/tomcat-orion/lib/annotations-api.jar: Permission denied`

Here's the permission of the file and directories:

```
drwxr-xr--.   5 webadm01 webadm01   49 19:32 29 Th06     DATA00
drwxr-xr--.   3 webadm01 webadm01   26 18:29 22 Th06     tomcat
drwxrw-r--.   9 webadm01 webadm01   258 17:26 29 Th06    tomcat-orion
drwxr-xr--.   2 webadm01 webadm01   4096 10:28 23 Th06   lib
-rw-r--r--.   1 webadm01 webadm01   12373 05:19  4 Th06  annotations-api.jar
```

When I log in the server as ***webadm01***, I can run the command `ls -l /DATA00/tomcat/tomcat-orion/lib/annotations-api.jar` just fine.

What's wrong here?

**UPDATE**:

User **Jenkins** doesn't belong to the group webadm01

I tried `chmod 775` to all the directories, and then Jenkins sucessfully ran the command. As I understand, read permission is enough to run ls against a file/directory. Isn't it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need x on a directory ... [S/E explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/121163).

Read reads the directory listing (the index of a book), execute lets you operate on its contents (the chapters and contents). aka, look but don't touch!